What are random independent matrices with distribution $\mu$?
I am reading the following: https://www.mat.uc.cl/~jairo.bochi/docs/fur_revised.pdf
and I am confused form the get go. It says:
If $Y_1,Y_2 \cdots Y_n$ are random independent matrices with distribution $\mu$, then the limit:
$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\|Y_n\cdots Y_1\|$$
exists a.s and is constant byu the subadditive ergodic theorem.
I have very basic understanding of measure-theoretic probability so this statement confuses me.
Here is my understanding:
We start with a probability measure $\mu$ on $SL_{\pm}(2,\mathbb{R})$, it tells us how "likely" you are to get a given set of matrices. So the random variable could be the identity here? Say $I$ is the identity random variable, then $P(I \in A)=\mu(A)$ correct?
What is the set up to apply the subadditive ergodic theorem here? Some kind of shift? Shift on $SL_{\pm}(2,\mathbb{R})^\infty$?

A shift should work, since the $Y_i$ are i.i.d.
